# How do I stop a function in GUI using Tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I already have a cancel button but it cancels everything also the GUI window, I only want to assign the cancel button to a specific function. This is my exit:

```
def exit(self):
    return sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the function that you wish to stop, check a variable (cancel flag) which is set by your button's callback.

```
class App(Tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    cancelButton = Tk.Button(root, text="Cancel", command=lambda: setattr(self, "cancelFlag",True)
    cancelButton.pack()
  def function(self):
    # Loop
      if getattr(self, "cancelFlag", True):
        self.cancelFlag = False
        return
      # Rest of code
```